# Formatting the Field in Dsum

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my project I am using `dsum` to query a table to compare years.  But I want to render the `field` as a year for the comparison.

```
Public Function GetValue(whatyear) As Long
    GetValue = DSum("Modification", "Accounting Totals", "Format([EntryDate],'yyyy') = " & whatyear & " AND [ModType] like *2*")
End Function
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Syntax error (missing opeator in query expression
'Format([EntryDate],'yyyy' = 2016 AND [ModType] like *2*"
```

This is probably an easy one for you VBA Gurus.  What do I do?

Comment: isn't `*2*` supposed to be in quotes `'*2*'` ? and not sure why the `)` is not in the error message ..

Comment: Maybe, but it still gives the same error - no wait - now it says `invalid use of null`

Comment: I am not sure how comparison between string and number is handled, so maybe `"Year([EntryDate]) = "` or `"Format([EntryDate],'yyyy') = '" & whatyear & "' AND`

Comment: Hmmm...  yes, I have the same problem using `year()`.  I tried adding the single quotes but get the same error.

Comment: I have another one where I use `"Year([EntryDate]) = " & whatyear)` and *that* works, but I need the extra criteria on this one.  So I tried this with the same error: `"Year([EntryDate]) = " & whatyear & " AND [ModType] = 2"`

Comment: Got it - I had to remove the `As Long` from the function declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need qoutes for the year, and if [ModType] is text, you need qoutes for it  as well. in addition, handle null values like this, else if it doesn't find any rows, that will throw another error:

```
Nz(DSum("Modification", "Accounting Totals", "Format([EntryDate],'yyyy') = '" & whatyear & "' AND [ModType] like '*2*' "), 0)
```

if [ModType] is a numeric value, then the like operator is not going to work, you need to use another operator such as these: =, >=, <=, BETWEEN

Answer (score 2):

> Got it - I had to remove the As Long from the function declaration

If so, you may have zero records and DSum returns Null. Catch that - as O. Gungor showed - with Nz. And get the year as a number:

So:

```
Public Function GetValue(ByVal whatyear As Integer) As Currency
    GetValue = Nz(DSum("Modification", "Accounting Totals", "Year([EntryDate]) = " & whatyear & " AND [ModType] Like '*2*'"), 0)
End Function
```